# Android WebView doesn't load multiple pages

Tags: android, webview, delay

I'm trying to load multiple pages one after another, with a 30 seconds interval betweeen each load. This is my class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView wv;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        wv = new WebView(this);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        setContentView(wv);
        String[] urlArr =  {"http://www.google.com", "http://www.cnn.com", "http://www.wired.com"};
        int delay = 30 * 1000;
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        for(int i = 0; i < urlArr.length; i++) {
            MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable(urlArr[i]);
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
            delay = delay + 30 * 1000;
        }
    }

    private class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        private String url;

        public MyRunnable(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public void run() {
            wv.loadUrl(url);
            Log.d("MainActivity", "PageLoaded: " + url);
        }
    }

}
```

So, the logic is pretty simple: I've got a single WebView instance. Then, inside the for cycle I call `postDelayed()`. It loads only google.com, the other two are not loaded, even if the Log says "PageLoaded". Is there a solution using the `Handler`?

Comment: Just check out your secound url is called in your run method or not???

Comment: You cannot say "PageLoaded" there as with wv.loadUrl(url); you have only requested the wv to load that page. If you want to know when the page is loaded you have to implement onPageFinished() of your WebViewClient like this:  wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
 public void onPageFinished(WebView webview, String url) {
  Log.d("WebViewActivity", "onPageFinished() " + url);
  Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, "onPageFinished()\n" + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
WebViewActivity.this.setTitle ( url );
 }
   } And use int delay = 0; to start with.
          );

Comment: I know that "PageLoaded" is not the right way of logging, as you suggested the page is loaded only when onPageFinished is called back. It was just to check that the run() method inside MyRunnable was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved. Actually, the code that I've posted works. The problem comes when the pages that I wanted to load ask you to leave the page through a Javascript popup. You have two ways to handle this behaviour:

1. Instantiate `WebChromeClient` and handle the popup
2. Create single WebView instances and save them inside the inner class.

So, this solution (the second one) works as well, even if more memory expensive (maybe?):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String[] urlArr =  {"http://www.google.com", "http://www.cnn.com", "http://www.wired.com"};
        int delay = 30 * 1000;
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        for(int i = 0; i < urlArr.length; i++) {
            WebView wv = new WebView(this);
            wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable(urlArr[i], wv);
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
            delay = delay + 30 * 1000;
        }
    }

    private class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        private String url;
        private WebView wv;

        public MyRunnable(String url, WebView wv) {
            this.url = url;
            this.wv = wv;
        }

        public void run() {
            setContentView(wv);
            wv.loadUrl(url);
            Log.d("MainActivity", "PageLoaded: " + url);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that this helps someone, thank you anyway!